# Flutter RenderBox was not laid out on SingleChildScrollView

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm learning a course and I was coding along but I faced a problem that he didn't face. I added `SingleChildScrollView()` in a modal bottom sheet but I got the `RenderBox was not laid out` error but his code was working and mine not. I checked the code and everything is exactly the same.

here is my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final keyboardSpace = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
            16, width < 450 ? 70 : 10, 16, keyboardSpace + 16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _titleController,
              maxLength: 50,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                label: Text('Title'),
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              controller: _amountController,
              // maxLength: 50,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                prefixText: '\$ ',
                label: Text('Amount'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
              child: Text(_selectedDate == null
                  ? 'Date'
                  : formatter.format(_selectedDate!)),
            ),
            DropdownButton(
                value: _selectedCategory,
                items: Category.values
                    .map(
                      (category) => DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: category,
                        child: Text(
                          category.name.toUpperCase(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  if (value == null) {
                    return;
                  }
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedCategory = value;
                  });
                }),
            const Spacer(),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 15),
              child: Column(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  FilledButton(
                    onPressed: _submitExpenseData,
                    child: const Text('Save Expense'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Cancel'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

this is the error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPhysicalShape#3bfb0 relayoutBoundary=up4
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1966 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

I tried the `Expanded()` and `SizedBox()` and it didn't work.

If there is any confusion feel free to ask me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code snippet you have a **Spacer** widget inside of the **Column** which is wrapped inside of your **SingleChildScrollView**.

This leads to an error, because **Spacer** has a flex value of 1 and wants totake up available space. But because the **Column** is wrapped inside the **SingleChildScrollView**, it may not have any flex children ( if you don't want to use a rather expensive workaround).

Your simplest options are to either replace the **Spacer** widget with a **SizedBox** that has an explicit height.

Or you can also wrap the whole **Column** with a **SizedBox** widget with a larger height (like 500). Then your **Spacer** can again take up a portion of the available space, because the **Column** will now have an explicit height (before it would shrink to fit its content, because the **SingleChildScrollView** would pass unbound constraints)